# alter default privileges of certain column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want a RoleGroup to have certain privileges on a specific column in a table ….the roleGroup not DB owner :

```
 grant  SELECT, INSERT ,UPDATE  (colOne) on table schemaOne.tableOne 
 to roleGroup;
```

When I want alter default privileges of this column (to include future users), I get ERROR saying can’t alter default privileges of one column only :

```
alter default privileges for role DB_OWNER in schema schemaOne grant 
select,insert,update(colOne) on table schemaOne.tableOne to 
roleGroup;
```

which forced me to do this :

```
Alter Default priviliges for role DB_OWNER in schema schemOne grant 
select,insert,update to roleGroup ;
```

what’s the point of the first grant then ?!!  Or am I making some mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole question is a bit unclear as both of your statements are syntactically incorrect.

`GRANT` grants privileges on *existing* objects, while `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` defines what privileges will automatically be granted to objects *created in the future*. So the scope of these statements does not overlap, but they complement each other.

I guess you misunderstood that point, otherwise you wouldn't try to `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` on an existing table.

A valid form would be:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE db_owner IN SCHEMA schemaone
   GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON TABLES TO rolegroup;
```

This will grant the privileges on all tables created in that schema by `db_owner` *in the future*.

The title of your question suggests that you are wondering why you cannot use `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` to grant privileges on columns.

The likely answer is that not all future tables need to have a column `colone`, and what should happen with tables that don't have a column of that name. You might argue that no privileges should be granted in that case, and I guess that is a valid option. But it seems hard to come up with a use case for that, which may explain why nobody has considered implementing such a feature so far.

Alternatively, your desire could be that a column that will be added to an existing table in the future should automatically receive the privileges, but again I don't consider such a feature as very useful.

Comment: @Laurenze Albe ; 1- You right about the incorrect syntax , 2- you draw my attention to some good points..Thanks.